# Using Jquery: How do I gracefully resize a Parent div after hiding a child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

Using Jquery: How do I gracefully resize a Parent div after hiding a child div?
This code works to hide the Option1 as I want but then the container div SLAMS shut in a jarring way.
Can I chain something on to the end to gracefully resize the div to fit the new size after the Option1 hides?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Option1">
        Users can do things here
    </div>

    <div id="Option2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="optout">I opt out of the other options
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
$('#optout').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $('#Option1').hide("drop");
    } else {
        $('#Option1').show("drop");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?: http://jsfiddle.net/hJ8tL/

Comment: this works but after the option1 hides, the container div slams shut. is there something i can add to get it to "Slide" to the smaller size after the child option1 is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for jquery

```
$('#optout').click(function () {
    $('#Option1').slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Comment: This led to the desired effect. Thank you.


    $('#optout').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $('#Option1').slideUp("slow");
    } else {
        $('#Option1').slideDown("slow");
    }
});